# Why I can't import my own module to my own code?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a file structure like:

```
- main.py
- Classes
    - worksheet.utilities.py
```

I have in file worksheet.utitlities.py a class named WorkSheetUtilities.
I would like to import it to main.py file and use it. I just can't do that.

I have tried those:

```
from ..Classes.worksheet.utilities import *
from ..Classes import WorkSheetUtilities
import Classes.worksheet.utilities as ws_util
from Classes import WorkSheetUtilities
```

But nothing works.

Can anyone write to me about what I am doing wrong? How can I import this class?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is worksheet a directory? I would also not recommend naming a directory Classes.

You can try:
from Classes.worksheet.utilities import WorkSheetUtilities

Comment: The `.` is already used to indicate the directory structure, so extra `.` in the filename you use for your module will not work. `..Classes.worksheet.utilities` cannot mean the `worksheet.utilities.py` file in `Classes`; it must mean `utilities.py` which is in `worksheet`, which is in `Classes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `worksheet.utilities` to something like `worksheet_utilities` and import as

```
from Classes.worksheet_utilities import *
```

Comment: Thank you. That solution works. In PHP usually I named classes with a dot so I understand that in Python it must be with "_". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which IDE are you using ? This can be an issue with you IDE settings.

Try following :

1.**For Pycharm**: Try setting parent directory as source directory

- Right-click on parent directory >> Mark Directory as >> Sources Root

2.**For VScode** : Try creating a pylintrc file and set init hook

- `pylint --generate-rcfile`
- update key `init-hook =  import sys; sys.path.append("your_project_location")`